# how to store an object inside session in zend framewrok 2?

Tags: php, session, object, zend-framework2, zend-session

i am wondering if i can store a object inside session using zend frameworks 2

when i retrieve the object it needs to be an object and not an array

example object:

```
object(Zend\Stdlib\Parameters)[144]
  public 'name' => string 'test test' (length=9)
  public 'website' => string 'test.com' (length=8)
  ...
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Zend Framework 2, The session seems to be an associative array with key as `namespace`, and value as another associative array.

In order to manipulate the session, you can use an abstraction layer called `Container`

```
use Zend\Session\Container;

// namespace 'user'
$userContainer = new Container('user');

// Store the locale and devise
$userContainer->locale = 'fr-FR';
$userContainer->devise = 'Euro';
```

to write what you want under a specific namespace.
You can later retrieve you data with:

```
use Zend\Session\Container;

// Create a container to manipulate session data
$userContainer = new Container('user');

// Check if the data exist under the namespace
if ( $userContainer->offsetExists('devise'))
{
    // Retrieve the data
    $devise = $userContainer->offsetGet('devise');
}
else
{
    // Get the default value
    $devise = 'Euro';
}
```

PS: Of course, be sure that the session is available

Comment: locale and devise are example, you can store what you want